# htaccess list directory and rewrite rules for it

Tags: list, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I'm trying to make a .htaccess code for automatically rewrite rules for a directory.
In example:

```
URL: https://example.com/assets/test.png
Folder: /src/assets/test.png
```

or,

```
URL: https://example.com/js/test.js
Folder: /src/js/test.js
```

My htaccess file:

```
#Rewrite to www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#remove html file extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

#remove php file extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

How can i make this?

Comment: Please share your htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please do try following rule in your .htaccess file once. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteRule ([\w-]+)\.png/?$ src/assets/$1.js [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: can i use this with other file extensions? Not only js or png

Comment: @BenMert, yes you can try to rewrite/redirect from specific format to another specific format(by adding their specific more rules in .htaccess file), as per your question I had written it from .png to .js  Let me know if this works for you.